# javascript button shrinks on Click

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, click

When clicking the buttons they are shrinking. -How is it possible to prevent the shrinking ?

```js
function aaa() {
  document.activeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#B2DD28';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0022</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0023</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0024</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0025</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0026</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0027</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0022</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0023</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0024</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0025</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0026</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0027</button>
```

Comment: Most likely you have some code somewhere that makes them shrink. Could you post the complete code?

Comment: Either provide a custom styles to the default button state (eg. set default background to white), or don't use native ``<button>`` element at all (which tries to use OS's native widgets).

Comment: @this.lau please click "run code snipped" -then you see the buttons are shrinking when clicking them. I don't have an own code to make them shrink.

Answer (score 0):

The button does not shrink, it's just that the border is of a different colour than the background. Probably the border is of a light colour so on a white background it looks like it's shrinking.

A solution would be to set the border colour to the same colour as the background as in the code below:

```js
function aaa() {
  document.activeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#B2DD28';
  document.activeElement.style.borderColor = '#B2DD28';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0022</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0023</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0024</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0025</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0026</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0027</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0022</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0023</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0024</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0025</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0026</button>
<button type="button" onclick="aaa()">0027</button>
```

Comment: the Buttons are indeed(!) shrinking in Firefox. Your sample code doesn't help. -See uploaded image https://snag.gy/ycw6po.jpg